# Reopen "why hasn't the hiring manager gotten back to me?"

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[Why hasn't the hiring manager gotten back to me?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/46819/2322)

I made an edit here to remove the "tell me what to do" stuff. I think in this case this question is pretty answerable, given the context of the question.

While perhaps simple, I think the edited question is on-topic.

Hoping to get some community reopen votes!

Comment: I voted to reopen after the edits as I feel it may now be answerable :)

Answer (score 3):

It's still closed because, after the edits, the question boils down to:

> Why hasn't the hiring manager gotten back to me?

We can't know that. Therefore the question isn't answerable.